# Impossible to install package dplyr (tibble.so requires version 3.4.0)

Tags: r, dplyr, package, installation

I am desperately trying to install package dplyr but nothing I have done helped (neither the previous posts about the suject). Here are the error message I am getting:

```
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/dplyr/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/tibble/libs/tibble.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/tibble/libs/tibble.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/tibble/libs/tibble.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: tibble.so requires version 3.4.0 or later, but libR.dylib provides version 3.3.0
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/dplyr’
```

Any chance somebody would know how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly did you run that generated that output? What is your `sessionInfo()`? Sounds like you are just running an old version of R that can't support the latest version of these packages.

Comment: any chance you can update to the current version of R (3.4.4)? Otherwise, seems as though you'll have to find/follow instructions for installing older versions of packages.

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker. Changing version solved the problem. I was first on 3.4.4 but had the same problem and reinstalled an older R version. Going back to 3.4.4 fixed the problem somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Changing version solved the problem. I was first on 3.4.4 but had the same problem and reinstalled an older R version. Going back to 3.4.4 fixed the problem somehow...